# Take string from a cell and find it in other cell in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, find

Below is my dataframe, I have four columns PN, COO,HTS, FTA.. I need to check whether the "PN" (string)available in the column HTS and FTA, if available, I need to have "PN" in new fields (HTS_Calc, FTA_calc).[image]

Comment: Are HTS and FTA strings or lists?

Comment: yes, separated by comma

Answer (score 1):

Just test if `HTS` and `FTA`  contains `PN`

```
df["HTS_Clc"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["PN"] if x["HTS"].find(x["PN"]) !=-1 else "",axis=1)
df["FTA_calc"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["PN"] if x["FTA"].find(x["PN"]) !=-1 else "",axis=1)
```

Output:

```
print(df)

    PN       HTS       FTA HTS_Clc FTA_calc
0  abc  abc, 123  123, 567     abc         
1  123  abc, 123  123, 567     123      123
2  567  abc, 123  123, 567              567
```

Comment: it works fine, however curios to understand about the script, can you brief little bit about the script, especially why "!=-1"?

Comment: @KesavanSurya basiclly we return `PN` if the the substring was found if not `find`return -1 so we return empty string, also if my answer was helpful consider accepting!

Comment: HI Yefet.. your answer if really helpful.. but one more issue I am facing.. in the above example, if any string (seperated by comma) in HTS or FTA column matches with PN, then returns the value in HTS_Calc or FTA_calc. I want to have this function with exact match but the above script works based on substring match. Say, if HTS contains '1234', then it should not return value in 'HTS_Cacl' but the current script return this. would be great if you help me with this.